# Found elements with non-unique id

Tags: python, jquery, django

I have 3 posts on homepage and each have a comment form, I am using one form for all posts. I am using jQuery to disabled submit button if there are no text in input and also enable submit button if there is text in input. The problem is that each post submit button have same ID, how do i make button a unique id for each post ID?

```
 <span class="md-form">
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="feeds-form form-inline md-form form-sm" method="POST" action="{% url 'site:home' %}">

  {% csrf_token %}

  <input type="hidden" value={{post.id}} name="post_comment">

  <textarea name="comment_post" class="textinput textInput" placeholder="Add a comment..." required="" id="id_comment_post{{ post.id }}" onkeyup="if(this.textLength != 0) {submit.disabled = false} else {submit.disabled = true}"></textarea>

  <button type="submit" id="submit" disabled><i class="fas fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
  </form>
```

```
  <style>
 .feed-form .fa-paper-plane{color:grey;}
 .feed-form .fa-paper-plane:hover{color:blue;}
 .feed-form #submit[disabled]{opacity:0.5;}
  </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try following code:

```
<button type="submit" id="submit-{{post.id}}" class="submit" disabled><i class="fas fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

and in css

```
.feed-form .submit[disabled]{opacity:0.5;}
```

Updated code:

```
<span class="md-form">
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="feeds-form form-inline md-form form-sm" method="POST" action="{% url 'site:home' %}">

 <input type="hidden" value={{post.id}} name="post_comment">

  <textarea name="comment_post" class="textinput textInput" placeholder="Add a comment..." required="" id="id_comment_post{{ post.id }}" onkeyup=""></textarea>

  <button type="submit" id="submit1" class="submit" disabled>button</button>
  </form>
  </span>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).on("keydown",".textinput",function(){
    let buttons = $(this).closest("form").find(".submit")
  if($(this).val() == "") {
  buttons.attr("disabled",true);

  }
  else{
    buttons.attr("disabled",false);
  }
});
```

Comment: @m354...your answer solved the non-unique id, but there is a problem, the #submit in css is not working. When I use your code, the form refuses to submit. I updated my question, you can please take a look

Comment: try adding a class in button tag: class="submit"  like <button type="submit" class="submit" id="submit-{{post.id}}" disabled> button <button> and in css use: 
feed-form .submit[disabled]{opacity:0.5;}... 
I alread update my answer. take a look

Comment: @m354...Same problem, when I type in input the button is still disabled.

Comment: can you please share your  ontype button enable/disable code  ?

Comment: @m354...enable/disable code is in template in textarea, onkeyup="if(this.textLength != 0) {submit.disabled = false} else {submit.disabled = true}"

Comment: please look the code here.. ontype button is enabled : https://jsfiddle.net/mehdi354/c3wyh761/3/

Comment: This worked as my first code, the problem is that I got Found elements with non-unique id

Comment: I have changed few things here as you can see in the updated answer.instead of using onkeyup you use separate <script></script> tag . check my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/mehdi354/c3wyh761/13/

Comment: Thanks it worked, you can update your answer, I added this; id="submit1-{{post.id}}"

Comment: Your code only work for the first form submit button, when I submit a comment in second post, button do not return to disabled state, it turns enabled. How do I make button turn disabled when form is submitted.

Comment: You can try the code from here: https://jsfiddle.net/mehdi354/c3wyh761/14/