# Comment form only submit once using Ajax

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

i have implemented a comment form to every posts of users, i have 3 posts on homepage. The first post submit comment only ones, when submit a second comment it saved in database but it displayed an error "Undefined", while the other posts submits comments normally as i wanted. What is missing in my code that is causing such error for the first post of user?

[image]

Views:

```
def home(request):
    #Comment form homepage
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_id = request.POST.get("post_comment")
        post_obj = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.commented_image = post_obj
            comment.save()
            # return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    context = {'form':form}
    if request.is_ajax():
    html = render_to_string('ajax_newfeeds_comments.html', context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse({'form': html})

    return render(request,'home.html', context)
```

Ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//HomeFeeds Comment
$(document).on('submit', '.feeds-form', function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 console.log($(this).serialize());
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "{% url 'site:home' %}",
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    $('#newfeeds-form').html(response['form']);
    $('textarea').val('');
  },
  error: function(rs, e) {
    console.log(rs.resopnseText);
  },
});
});
</script>
```

Template:

```
  <span class="md-form">
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="feeds-form form-inline md-form form-sm" method="POST" action="{% url 'site:home' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" value={{post.id}} name="post_comment">
  <textarea name="comment_post" class="textinput textInput animated fadeIn" placeholder="Add a comment..." required="" id="id_comment_post{{ post.id }}" onkeyup=""></textarea>

  <button type="submit" class="submit" id="submit1-{{post.id}}" disabled><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
  </form>
  </span>
```

Comment: i don't know much know about python ,still i suspect an error in your textarea you have given `name="comment_post"` but in your Views you are getting it using `...get("post_comment")` .Isn't that should be `.get("comment_post") `

Comment: @Swati...I have an hidden type in inputv name="post_comment" that is the value I'm getting from views. The name in textarea is what I'm getting from forms.py. That is not the solution

Comment: @MrHize You have a "500 Internal Server Error" on your request - give it a look here [HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_errors). It seems to be an error in your python script. Further you can use the `complete` method of the ajax request to get more informations - [more informations here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: @UfguFugullu..thanks your links helped a lot. I have got it working now.

Comment: @UfguFugullu.. I have a problem in and question I made yesterday, the submit for button only disabled when no text inside textarea, when I add text in textarea the button is enabled, but when the form is submitted the button remains enabled without text in textarea. How do I make button disable immediately as the form is submitted? This is the link to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61729241/found-elements-with-non-unique-id/61729471?noredirect=1#comment109208077_61729471

Comment: @MrHize Please add a new question with all informations so we can help you there and post a working example in an answer. You should post your solution as an answer in this question and mark it as "answered".

Comment: @UfguFugullu.. OK I will, just check on the link all codes are there.

Comment: @MrHize Do you create a new question for your submit button problem?

Comment: @UfguFugullu..Yes, check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61748605/how-do-i-disabled-enabled-submit-button

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i solved the problem. Ajax was not set properly, this solved the problem.

```
<script>
$(document).on('submit', '.feeds-form', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var pk = $(this).attr('value');
console.log($(this).serialize());
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "{% url 'site:home' %}",
  headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val() },
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    $('#newfeeds-form'+pk).html(response['form']);
     $('textarea').val('');
  },
  error: function(rs, e) {
    console.log(rs.resopnseText);
  },
});
});
</script>
```