# How do i disabled/enabled submit button

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

i am working on a project using Django. I have 3 posts in homepage and each have a comment form with a submit button. How do i disable the submit button if there is no text in textarea and when there is a text in textarea the submit button will be enabled, after form is submitted the submit button will become disabled. My comment saved in database when i submit the form, I have tried using this http://jsfiddle.net/mehdi354/c3wyh761/14/ it worked but my comment is not saving in database. How do i solve this?

[image]

Form:

```
<span class="md-form">
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="feeds-form form-inline md-form form-sm" method="POST" action="{% url 'site:home' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" value={{post.id}} name="post_comment">
  <textarea name="comment_post" class="textinput textInput animated fadeIn" placeholder="Add a comment..." required="" id="id_comment_post{{ post.id }}" onkeyup=""></textarea>

  <button type="submit" class="submit" id="submit1-{{post.id}}" disabled>button</button>
  </form>
</span>
```

Ajax form submit:

```
<script>
$(document).on('submit', '.feeds-form', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var pk = $(this).attr('value');
console.log($(this).serialize());

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "{% url 'site:home' %}",
  headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val() },
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    $('#newfeeds-form'+pk).html(response['form']);
     $('textarea').val('');
    //console.log($('#newfeeds-form'+pk).html(response['form']));
  },
  error: function(rs, e) {
    console.log(rs.resopnseText);
  },
});
});
</script>
```

Jquery disable/enable button:

```
$(document).on("keydown",".textinput",function(){
let buttons = $(this).closest("form").find(".submit")
if($(this).val() == "") {
buttons.attr("disabled",true);  
}
else{
  buttons.attr("disabled",false);
}
$(document).on("click",".submit",function(e){
$(this).closest("form").trigger("reset");;
$(this).attr("disabled",true);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: What should the variable "pk" contains on your line `var pk = $(this).attr('value');` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve it with the `beforeSend` and the `complete` method. You find informations about it [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.feeds-form').on('submit', onSubmitFeedsForm);
  $('.feeds-form .textinput').on({
    'keyup': onKeyUpTextInput,
    'change': onKeyUpTextInput // if another jquery code changes the value of the input
  });

  function onKeyUpTextInput(event) {
    var textInput = $(event.target);
    textInput.parent().find('.submit').attr('disabled', textInput.val() == '');
  }

  function onSubmitFeedsForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // if you need to use elements more than once try to keep it in variables
    var form = $(event.target);
    var textInput = form.find('.textinput');
    var hiddenField = form.find('input[name="post_comment"]');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "{% url 'site:home' %}",
      // use the variable of the "form" here
      data: form.serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function() {
        // beforeSend will be executed before the request is sent
        form.find('.submit').attr('disabled', true);
      },
      success: function(response) {
        // as a hint: since you get a json formatted response you should better us "response.form" instead of response['form']
        $('#newfeeds-form' + hiddenField.val()).html(response.form);
        // do you really want to reset all textarea on the whole page? $('textarea').val('');
        textInput.val(''); // this will trigger the "change" event automatically
      },
      error: function(rs, e) {
        console.log(rs.resopnseText);
      },
      complete: function() {
        // this will be executed after "success" and "error"
        // depending on what you want to do, you can use this in the "error" function instead of here
        // because the "success" function will trigger the "change" event automatically
        textInput.trigger('change');
      }
    });
  }

});
```

```css
.feeds-form .submit[disabled] {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="md-form">
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="feeds-form form-inline md-form form-sm" method="POST" action="{% url 'site:home' %}">
    <!-- {% csrf_token %} -->
    <input type="hidden" value={{post.id}} name="post_comment">
    <textarea name="comment_post" class="textinput textInput animated fadeIn" placeholder="Add a comment..." required="" id="id_comment_post{{ post.id }}" onkeyup=""></textarea>

    <button type="submit" class="submit" id="submit1-{{post.id}}" disabled="disabled"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i> Submit</button>
  </form>
</span>

<span class="md-form">
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="feeds-form form-inline md-form form-sm" method="POST" action="{% url 'site:home' %}">
    <!-- {% csrf_token %} -->
    <input type="hidden" value={{post.id}} name="post_comment">
    <textarea name="comment_post" class="textinput textInput animated fadeIn" placeholder="Add a comment..." required="" id="id_comment_post{{ post.id }}" onkeyup=""></textarea>

    <button type="submit" class="submit" id="submit1-{{post.id}}" disabled="disabled"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i> Submit</button>
  </form>
</span>
```

Comment: @UfguFugullu...your code saved comment in database but there is an error. The text in textarea still remain in textarea. i will upload the error i got from your code

Comment: @UfguFugullu..i have update my question with the error i got using your code

Comment: I have an input type="hidden" value="{{post.id}}"  I'm using this; var pk = $(this).attr('value'); to get the pk of each values in hidden input, so I pass the pk to Ajax response. This makes comments saved successfully in every post, if I have to remove pk, then only the first post form will not be saved.

Comment: @MrHize You write the code $('#newfeeds-form'+pk).html(response['form']);. I don't know exactly what the variable pk should contains. And I don't know if the element will exist. That's why I have created the pk variable and filled it just with "?" - that will be the problem

Comment: I replaced my code with yours, or should I include your code to mine?

Comment: @MrHize I have edited my answer and changed the `pk` variable by using the new `hiddenField`

Comment: Thanks its working now. This also worked, var pk = $(this).attr('value'); but no data displayed in chrome console?

Comment: Because the `console.log()` is missing?

Comment: @UfguFugullu...I think you have to see this question based on your code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61750906/how-do-i-update-comment-count-using-ajax