# How do i query for comment in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am new in Django and I have been following tutorials online. I am having problem on how to display the comments. 
How do i query for comments in views, so i can display comments for a particular post.

Model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    poster_profile = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True)
    image_caption = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class Comments (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True)
    commented_image = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    comment_post = models.TextField()
```

Views.py:

```
def home_view(request):
    comment = Comments.objects.all() #This is getting all comment in all post, how do i query for comment in a particular post.
    context{'comment':comment}
    return render(...)
```

Template:

```
{% for com in comment %}
<p>{{ com.comment_post }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
post = Post.objects.get(id=1)
comment = post.comments_set.all()
```

**[Following Relationships "Backward"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)**

> If a model has a ForeignKey, instances of the foreign-key model will have access to a Manager that returns all instances of the first model. By default, this Manager is named FOO_set, where FOO is the source model name, lowercased. This Manager returns QuerySets, which can be filtered and manipulated as described in the “Retrieving objects” section above.

Note this behaviour can be overridden.

> You can override the FOO_set name by setting the related_name parameter in the ForeignKey definition. For example, if the Entry model was altered to blog = ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='entries'), the above example code would look like this:

Edit #2:

**views.py:**

```
def home_view(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all().reverse()[5]

    context{ 'posts': posts, }
    return render(...)
```

Now in your templates you can do something like:

```
{% if posts %}
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.image_caption }}


    {% for comment in post.comments_set.all %}
        {{ comment.comment_post }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I got an error, Post matching query does not exist.

Comment: I'm getting same error and it's pointing at, post = Post.objects.get(id=1)

Comment: what about N+1 problem?

Comment: Check the Post model, it does not have and id field.

Comment: @Hisham.. Same error, Post matching query does not exist

Comment: @Hisham.. It seems I'm getting the error because there is no post with id=1

Comment: @Hisham..I have watched lots of tutorials on YouTube, I'm now working on a website, just trying to create one for myself. I have list of posts by users, and each post have a comment form, just like Facebook new feeds. But comment is displaying in all post.

Comment: @Hisham... Comment do not display. I know a related_name could do this, like: {% for comment in post.comments.all %} {{ comment.comment_post }} {% endfor %}. But is there a way I can query comment for each post without related_name?

Comment: @Hisham...comment still do not display. Is there no way i can query for the  id of the post?

Comment: @Hisham___Pak..Thanks i will check it

Comment: @Hisham... Not displaying comments

Comment: @Hisham.. Still not displaying comments

Comment: @Hisham.. Please help me out with this, when form is submitted using Ajax, it doesn't display comment, it just displays empty text, but in chrome console it displays the comment. I believe Ajax is working properly, but comment is not displaying. Please help me out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61768085/displaying-comments-using-ajax

Answer (score 0):

First of all, take a look at Django queryset documentation, especially [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for this kind of issues (to reduce number of queries to database). I didn't try but following snippet must work.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    poster_profile = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image_caption = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class Comments (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    commented_image = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_nam="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment_post = models.TextField()

...

def home_view(request):
    post = Post.objects.filter(id=request.data.get('post_id')).select_related("comments") # specify the post anyhow ..
    comments = post.comments
    context{'comment': comments}
    return render(...)
```

Comment: @ilhnctn...i got an error WSGIRequest object has no attribute data

Comment: can you try `request.body `?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780060/trying-to-parse-request-body-from-post-in-django

Answer (score -1):

```
def home_view(request):
particular_Post= Post.objects.get(id=1)
    comment = Comments.objects.get(Post=particular_Post)
context{'comment':comment}
return render(...)
```

to understund Query in django i suggest U to start by

```
python manage.py shell
```

and Import you're Models

Comment: @Zouhair...thanks but this doesn't answer to my question